# After clear Angular search box, Table data not appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, html-table

I am working on html and angularJs project,I have implemented search using angularJs on table data. It working fine for small table, but here I am having around 70 rows and 10-12 col in my table(pagination 10 rows). When I perform search if it matches, sometimes all data don't appears after clearing search box. If data don't matches it makes scrollbar disappear and no data shown in table even if I clear the search box, It takes the table at the starting column and there is no way to reach last column e.g.10th column.
Actually there are many columns so I have applied a [fix header and column](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/). Even after removing the fix header data does not appear after clear search box.

**Search implemented using below code.(1st row)**

```
<tr style="background:#669950;">
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty class="clearable" style="width:100px;display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.col1" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.col1.length" ng-click="search.col1=''"></a></td>
                    ......</tr>

$scope.objects = [{"col1":"t1","col2":"t2","col3":"t3","col4":"t4"},
                {"col1":"t1","col2":"t2","col3":"t3","col4":"t4"},{"col1":"t1","col2":"t2","col3":"t3","col4":"t4"},{"col1":"t1","col2":"t2","col3":"t3","col4":"t4"}];

                });
```

**Before performing search table appears like this**

[image]

**After performing search table appears like this**

[image]

How can I get scrollbar and all data in table when search is not found and after clear the search box?

Comment: show the angular code please.

Comment: I am using just angular object as I have added js code above.